# Showing functions are continuous but unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

> If a set $S$ contains an unbounded sequence, show that the function $f
>  : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x) = x$ for all $x$ in $S$
>   is continuous but unbounded.

**My attempt:**

Suppose a set $S$ contains an unbounded sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, and define the function $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in S$. We wish to show that $f$ is continuous but unbounded. By the definition of continuity, we must have that if $\{x_{n}\}$ converges to $x_{0}$, then the image sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}$ converges to $f(x_{0})$. But since $f$ is defined by $f(x) = x$, we can write

$$|f(x_{n}) - f(x_{0})| = |x_{n} - x_{0}|,$$

and this condition becomes the same as the first one (we can choose the same $N$ so that for all $\epsilon > 0$, the expression above is less than $\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$).  Thus, $f$ is continuous. Now, I just need to show $f$ is unbounded. I'm not so sure about how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is unbounded you need to show that for any supposed upper-bound $M$ on $f$, there is exists a value $f(x)$ which is greater than $M$. For your case where $f(x) = x$, the function is clearly unbounded since the sequence ${x_n}$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what $S$ is. If it is a subset of $\mathbb  R$ then $f(x)=x$ is continuous because it the identity map is continuous in the whole of $\mathbb  R$. Your proof is unnecessary.  For the second part if $s_n$ is an unbounded sequece in $S$ then $f(s_n)=s_n$ is unbounded, so $f$ is an unbounded fucntion.

Comment: Yes, $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.